# Old Miller projections Bipolar Oblique Conic Conformal/Oblated Stereographic definitions?

Tags: coordinate-system, proj, osgeo

I'm attempting to georeference and warp some old toposheets that are various old projections including the following:

```
Miller Oblated Stereographic Projection
Bipolar Oblique Conic Conformal
```

What's the best approach to acquiring the definition for this projection?  Or do I just have to use ArcGIS which seems to have these defined, note I have ArcGis available, but not for a while.

Comment: ArcInfo workstation has Bipolar oblique, ArcGIS (desktop/server) doesn't. No ArcGIS software supports Miller oblated stereographic.

Comment: Thanks, I think I have ArcInfo available as I work for a University that has a full ESRI licence I believe.  I guess if I add more GCP for the stereographic and use polynomial order 3 then i should improve the coverage, but it's going to end up quite distorted.